# PHP: Uncaught ImagickException: PDFDelegateFailed

Tags: php, pdf, imagemagick, ghostscript

I want to generate images from pdf pages in PHP. I am using imagick php extention to achieve this but I am getting error below when i am tring to read pdf file by imagick

```
Fatal error: Uncaught ImagickException: PDFDelegateFailed `The system cannot find the file specified. ' @ error/pdf.c/ReadPDFImage/801
```

My code is

```
$imagick = new Imagick();
$imagick->readImage(dirname(__FILE__). '/test.pdf');
```

My Server details from phpinfo()

```
PHP: Version 7.0.13
System: Windows NT LALMANI-PC 6.1 build 7601 (Windows 7 Ultimate Edition Service Pack 1) i586, Architecture: x86
imagick module version: 3.4.3
Imagick using ImageMagick library version: ImageMagick 6.9.3-7 Q16 x86
```

I also installed ImageMagick-6.9.9-27 and Ghostscript 9.22 in my system.

Please let me know what is wrong here. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got issue in Ghostscript 9.22 installation that was 64-bit, I uninstalled that and installed Ghostscript 9.22 32-bit. Issue Fixed.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I have 64 bit setup of ghostscript and imagick but I am facing the same issue, How can I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

ImageMagick can't find Ghostscript. The most usual reason for this is that the Ghostscript path is not in the $PATH environment variable, so IM doesn't know where to find it.

Add the Ghostscript installation path (which will vary depending on your OS and the package you use if its a Linux flavour and you us a package) to the $PATH environment variable for the user whic is active when your PHP script runs.

Answer (score 1):

**You don't need to reinstall GhostScript**, and, simply adding it to the $PATH will not necessarily solve your problem :/

Here is what you need to do :

1. On Windows, Ghostscript program is called something like `gswin64.exe`, so you simply need to rename the file to make it look like `gs.exe`
2. And, yeah, make sure the script can be found in the $PATH

Answer (score -1):

I have a same issue when i try convert pdf to image.

```
$imagick = new Imagick();
$imagick->readImage(dirname(__FILE__). '/test.pdf');
```

My solution in WINDOWS. Execute terminal shell of php :)

```
shell_exec('magick -density 200 C:\laragon\www\cobupemws\public\6258.pdf[0] -quality 100 C:\laragon\www\cobupemws\public\testDemoterminal.jpg');
```

My solution in LINUX. Execute terminal shell of php :)

```
shell_exec('convert -density 300 -background white -quality 100  -alpha remove 1.pdf test.jpg');
```