# Fatal error: Uncaught ImagickException: PDFDelegateFailed

Tags: php, ghostscript, imagick, apache2.4

I want to display PDF files like image files on my WebPage on Apache2.4 on PHP7 in Windows 2008 Server, but I'm having the next error:

Fatal error: Uncaught ImagickException: PDFDelegateFailed

I already have installet ImageMagick-7.0.8-Q16 and Ghostscript 9.27 (32 bits) I replace Ghostcript 9.27 - 64 bits because the Apache Server shutdown inmediatly and restart. Here I found this note here: [PHP: Uncaught ImagickException: PDFDelegateFailed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47969371/php-uncaught-imagickexception-pdfdelegatefailed) .

On Command Line window:

If I run magick file.pdf file.jpg it's work.

If I run magick -verbose file.pdf file.jpg it's work and i see that it's using gswin32c.exe.

I have the same WebPage on my computer with Win10 Pro, same Imagick version, same ghostscript version, same Apache version, same PHP version and it's working fine.

```
$pdfInfo = new Spatie\PdfToImage\Pdf($file);
while ($page < $pdfInfo->getNumberOfPages()) {
  $imagick = new Imagick();
  $imagick->setResolution(100, 100);
  $imagick->readImage(sprintf('%s[%s]', $file, $page));
  echo sprintf('<img src="data:image/%s;base64,%s" ><br>', $type, base64_encode($imagick));
  $page++;
```

Comment: You're talking about a Ghostscript installation issue that your resolved. What's your problem now ?

Comment: I am having the next error: Fatal error: Uncaught ImagickException: PDFDelegateFailed , on Windows 2008 Server.

Comment: OK. Please edit your question by adding the full error message and any information which may help.

Comment: What about the post you linked in your question ? Doesn't it help you ?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52861946/imagemagick-not-authorized-to-convert-pdf-to-an-image/52863413#52863413

Comment: @Demient that post help me.on Windows10, not in 2008.

Comment: @fmw42 I will try it. Thanks.

Comment: @fmw42, I just read that post. My policy.xml doesn'tt have module domain, just coder.

Comment: Some policies use coder. Change the one that uses PDF so that it is read|write.

Comment: This it is just a bit part for the whole file policy.xml.

Domains include system, delegate, coder, filter, path, or resource.

  Rights include none, read, write, execute, and all.  Use | to combine them,
  for example: "read | write" to permit read from, or write to, a path.

    <policy domain="coder" rights="read|write" pattern="{GIF,JPEG,PNG,WEBP}" />

Comment: I have added the next line on policy.xml:   <policy domain="coder" rights="read|write" pattern="{PDF}" />, but it donesn't work. I had the same error.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the Ghostscript version. I had to replace the gs executable file from the Ghostscript page for the last version and it works fine.